# Get video in Phpicker in swiftui, but can't play by Videoplayer

Tags: swift, swiftui, video-player, avkit

I'm trying to load a video from Phpicker and preview it by Video player, but I don't know why it doesn't work.

So I did some research, and most of the solutions put videos in the project file and use `Bundle.main.url(forResource:, withExtension:)` to play video.

Here's my picker to pick a video. I'm trying to get the video file URL and make a copy using `FileManager.default.copyItem(at:, to:)` then use URL in Avplayer.

(Pick a video from the photo library)

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {                        
    guard let videoURL = videoURL as? URL else { return }
    debugPrint("video url: \(videoURL.absoluteString)")
    let fileID = UUID().uuidString
    let fileName = "\(fileID).mp4"
    debugPrint("file name: \(fileName)")
    let newURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: NSTemporaryDirectory() + fileName)
    debugPrint("new url: \(newURL.absoluteString)")
    try? FileManager.default.copyItem(at: videoURL, to: newURL)
    self.parent.video = newURL
}
```

(User new URL to play video)

```
if let url = providerRoomSummitViewModel.roomIntroVideoURL {
    VStack {
        VideoPlayer(player: AVPlayer(url: URL))
    }
}
```

Comment: Why do you copy instead of use in-place? Did you check if it is really copied and present in file system by new URL?

Comment: Cuz I found this solution on the net, but it didn't work for me. I'm just wondering, could I use the file URL that gets from phpicker. I tried multiple times but it didn't work for me. like below.

itemProvider.loadItem(forTypeIdentifier: UTType.movie.identifier) { videoURL, error in
DispatchQueue.main.async {                        
         guard let videoURL = videoURL as? URL else { return }
         debugPrint("video url: \(videoURL.absoluteString)")
         self.parent.video = videoURL
     }
}